# How to Associate automated test cases to Azure through Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium Java & Eclipse IDE for web automation and want to associate the automation tests to Testcases which are already there in azure devops.
I know how to do that using the Visual Studio but want ti do same using eclipse...

Let me know if anyone have solution for this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Azure job, **Visual Studio Test task** which also associate tests with **Test Plans** in Azure, [does not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) test frameworks, other than the: MSTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah.

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, and more) using the Visual Studio Test Runner. Other than MSTest-based tests, test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter, such as xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah, can also be executed.